# An infinite group is cyclic if and only if it is isomorphic to each of its non-trivial subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The question has been described in the title. How to prove it?

Comment: It must be "to each of its proper *non-trivial* subgroups"

Comment: Hint: What are the simplest non-trivial subgroups?

Comment: Ah, I get it. Suddenly it turns out to be quite easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at a cyclic subgroup generated by any element that is not the identity.